# Iterate over tensor in a custom loss function

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I need to use this loss function for a CNN the list_distance and list_residual are output tensors from hidden layers which are important to compute the loss, but when i execute the code it gives me back this error

TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.

Is there another way to iterate over tensors without the use of the costruct
x in X or convert it in a numpy array or using the backend function of keras?

```py
def DBL(y_true, y_pred, list_distances, list_residual, l=0.65):
    prob_dist = []
    Li = []

    # mean of the images power spectrum
    S = np.sum([np.power(np.abs(fp.fft2(residual)), 2)
                for residual in list_residual], axis=0) / K.shape(list_residual)[0]
    # log-ratio between the geometric and arithmetic of S
    R = np.log10((scistats.gmean(S) / np.mean(S)))

    for c_i, dis_i in enumerate(list_distances):
        prob_dist.append([
            np.exp(-dis_i) / sum([np.exp(-dis_j) if c_j != c_i else 0 for c_j, dis_j in enumerate(list_distances)])
        ])
    for count, _ in enumerate(prob_dist):
        Li.append(
            -1 * np.log10(sum([p_j for c_j, p_j in enumerate(prob_dist[count])
                               if y_pred[count] == 1 and count != c_j])))

    L0 = np.sum(Li)

    return L0 - l * R
```

Comment: Enable Tensorflow's eager execution mode as the error indicates

Comment: Is it possible to costruct the function in another way using the backend function instead of the eager mode?

Comment: Why would you want that instead of simple `tf.enable_eager_execution()` at the beginning of your script? But yeah, check `map_fn` as error indicates once again.

Comment: Using `tf.enable_eager_execution` in a script is bad practice.... it’s meant to be used when jamming around in a python interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a custom function to feed into `tf.map_fn()` - [Tensorflow dox](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn)

Mapper functions map (funnily enough) the existing object (tensor) into a new one using a function you define.

They apply the custom function to every element in the object, without all the mucking about with `for` loops.

For instance (non tested code, may not run - on my phone atm):

```
def custom(a):
    b = a + 1
    return b

original = np.array([2,2,2])
mapped = tf.map_fn(custom, original)
# mapped == [3, 3, 3] ... hopefully
```

Tensorflow examples all use `lambda` functions, so you might need to define your functions like that if the above doesn’t work. Tensorflow example:

```
elems = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
squares = map_fn(lambda x: x * x, elems)
# squares == [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]
```

Edit:

As an aside, map functions are much easier to parallelise than for loops - it is assumed that each element of an object is processed uniquely - so you can see a performance uplift by using them.

Edit 2:

For the "reduce sum, but not on this index" part, I would heavily recommend you start looking back at matrix operations... As mentioned, `map` functions work element-wise - they are not aware of other elements. A `reduce` function is what you want, but even they are finiky when you try and do "not this index" sums... also tensorflow is built around matrix ops... Not the MapReduce paradigm.

Something along these lines might help:

```
sess = tf.Session()
var = np.ones([3, 3, 3]) * 5

zero_identity = tf.linalg.set_diag(
    var, tf.zeros(var.shape[0:-1], dtype=tf.float64)
)
exp_one = tf.exp(var)
exp_two = tf.exp(zero_identity)
summed = tf.reduce_sum(exp_two, axis = [0,1])
final = exp_one / summed

print("input matrix: \n", var, "\n")
print("Identities of the matrix to Zero: \n", zero_identity.eval(session=sess), "\n")
print("Exponential Values numerator: \n", exp_one.eval(session=sess), "\n")
print("Exponential Values to Sum: \n", exp_two.eval(session=sess), "\n")
print("Summed values for zero identity matrix\n ... along axis [0,1]: \n", summed.eval(session=sess), "\n")
print("Output:\n", final.eval(session=sess), "\n")
```

Comment: is it possible to implement with map_fn a code like this

  for c_i, dis_i in enumerate(list_distances):
        prob_dist.append([
            np.exp(-dis_i) / sum([np.exp(-dis_j) if c_j != c_i else 0 for c_j, dis_j in enumerate(list_distances)])
        ])

Comment: I would advise you start thinking in terms of matrix operations. As mentioned in my edit, map functions work in an element wise fashion

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. I'm doing a custom loss function, so I need to use map_fn on both y_true and y_pred together . And when they're symbolic, i.e., placeholders without batch size hardcoded in, and without eager execution mode, I can't even stack y_true and y_pred together to pass in to map_fn. I get an OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError.